# Date format returned by mongoosejs

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

The date field in my mongodb database is saved under the following format

```
        "$date": "2012-01-05T19:47:56.474Z"
```

But somehow mongoose returns it as

```
        date: Wed, 04 Jan 2012 19:14:33 GMT
```

Why does the format change, is it something i am doing in the query ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the way a standard JavaScript Date object is formatted when printing.

You can print it out in ISO format using something like this:
[How do I output an ISO 8601 formatted string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573521/how-do-i-output-an-iso-8601-formatted-string-in-javascript)

Or you might try using a javascript date library for formatting such as:
http://arshaw.com/xdate/#Formatting

Answer (score 1):

The former format is [ISO 8601](http://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), the latter looks like [`Date.toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) in JavaScript.

These are just different textual representations of the same date, stored internally using some portable format like Unix time. Everything is fine.

Comment: I know it's fine it's just that I'm using timeago the jquery plugin and it seems to only work for the first time format :/ And trying to fix that i came across this