# Converting time to ISO 8601 format

Tags: javascript, iso8601

I'm reading from a RSS feed which outputs date/time in the following format:

> #### Day, DD Mon YYYY HH:MM:SS OFFSET

For example,

> #### Tue, 24 Apr 2012 08:15:00 -0700

Using JavaScript,I need to convert it to an ISO8601 string (via `Date.toISOString()` preferably).

Any assistance would be appreciated.

I haven't really worked with time in JS before, so I haven't got many ideas. Would it be possible to switch the offset to a time zone, and convert it as a JS Date object?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is converting the offset to actual time zones, then converting it with `Date.toISOString()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u can do that with the date object (at least it is working for me in chrome)

```
var test = new Date("Tue, 24 Apr 2012 08:15:00 -0700");
test.toISOString() // "2012-04-24T15:15:00.000Z"
```

I hope it is the correct output... not sure

Comment: Oh now I just feel dumb for not having tried that... Thanks for this.

Comment: I do not know how older browsers are dealing with it... but I think this should work cross-browser

Comment: I'm actually developing a Windows Sidebar gadget, which runs on HTML/JS/CSS. It's working well, I was over-thinking again...

Comment: Usually there's no reason to drop the timezone information. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/15302113/277267