# Datetime in isoformat in Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, datetime, date, time

In *Python* I have this code:

```
now =  datetime.now().isoformat()
if "." not in now:
  now = now + ".000000"
```

Can I achieve the same result in *Javascript*?

The resulting datetime should match this mask `%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f` because the datetime will be saved into the database and then I need to retrieve it from *Python* code with exactly this mask.

Comment: It would have helped if you had shown us the expected result... Yet, you might be interested in: http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format

Comment: @JMax "ISO format" is well known, and well defined.

Comment: I'm curious as to why you have the `if "." not in now` check? Is there some scenario where the iso format doesn't return `.`?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Good point. There was such a case before, but it was not retrieved from datetime.now() and the `.something` part was missing often. Maybe I could omit it now (I'm not sure).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I output an ISO-8601 formatted string in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573521/how-do-i-output-an-iso-8601-formatted-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last example on page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference:Global_Objects:Date

```
/* use a function for the exact format desired... */
function ISODateString(d){
 function pad(n){return n<10 ? '0'+n : n}
 return d.getUTCFullYear()+'-'
  + pad(d.getUTCMonth()+1)+'-'
  + pad(d.getUTCDate())+'T'
  + pad(d.getUTCHours())+':'
  + pad(d.getUTCMinutes())+':'
  + pad(d.getUTCSeconds())+'Z'}

var d = new Date();
console.log(ISODateString(d)); // prints something like 2009-09-28T19:03:12Z
```

Comment: And if you prefer jquery...there u go http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jquery-dateFormat

Comment: Looks good, I removed only the `Z` letter and can I get microseconds too? In my mask it's `.%f` part.

Comment: Or I will concatenate it with `.000000` string, to have a correct format.

Answer (score 3):

Did you look at [`Date.toISOString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) - the standard function for generating ISO 8601 dates?

Here's a Chrome console test:

```
> (new Date()).toISOString()
"2012-06-25T10:55:19.833Z"
```

Note that the link above includes a shim which adds support for this function to browsers that don't already have it.

Comment: @InternalServerError if you look at the link I included the MDN site includes a shim for older browsers.

Comment: Thanks for answer, actually I use it in Firefox extension, so the other solution suits better to my need.

Comment: @xralf you should use the standard function, and shim it when not available.

Comment: @Alnitak But I don't have the `Z` letter in the end. Python omits the Z letter.

Comment: so just do `.substring(-1)` on it then - the `Z` suffix _is_ part of ISO 8601 format.