# Converting a normal date to ISO-8601 format

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I output an ISO-8601 formatted string in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573521/how-do-i-output-an-iso-8601-formatted-string-in-javascript)

I have a date like

```
Thu Jul 12 2012 01:20:46 GMT+0530
```

How can I convert it into ISO-8601 format like this

```
2012-07-12T01:20:46Z
```

Comment: Try not to drop the timezone information. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/15302113/277267

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In most newer browsers you have `.toISOString()` method, but in IE8 or older you can use the following (taken from [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js#L48) by Douglas Crockford):

```
// Override only if native toISOString is not defined
if (!Date.prototype.toISOString) {
    // Here we rely on JSON serialization for dates because it matches 
    // the ISO standard. However, we check if JSON serializer is present 
    // on a page and define our own .toJSON method only if necessary
    if (!Date.prototype.toJSON) {
        Date.prototype.toJSON = function (key) {
            function f(n) {
                // Format integers to have at least two digits.
                return n < 10 ? '0' + n : n;
            }

            return this.getUTCFullYear()   + '-' +
                f(this.getUTCMonth() + 1) + '-' +
                f(this.getUTCDate())      + 'T' +
                f(this.getUTCHours())     + ':' +
                f(this.getUTCMinutes())   + ':' +
                f(this.getUTCSeconds())   + 'Z';
        };
    }

    Date.prototype.toISOString = Date.prototype.toJSON;
}
```

Now you can safely call `.toISOString() method.

Comment: Like this you'll overwrite the ECMA Script 5 method, also for the [browsers that support it](http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/). Please add a condition.

Comment: Good catch, @BeatRichartz! I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Usually there's no reason to drop the timezone information. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/15302113/277267

Answer (score 6):

There's the `.toISOString()` method on date. You can use that for Browsers with support for ECMA-Script 5. For those without, install the method like this:

```
if (!Date.prototype.toISOString) {
    Date.prototype.toISOString = function() {
        function pad(n) { return n < 10 ? '0' + n : n };
        return this.getUTCFullYear() + '-'
            + pad(this.getUTCMonth() + 1) + '-'
            + pad(this.getUTCDate()) + 'T'
            + pad(this.getUTCHours()) + ':'
            + pad(this.getUTCMinutes()) + ':'
            + pad(this.getUTCSeconds()) + 'Z';
    };
}
```

Comment: Could you please reindent that code?