# How to use date based generic view in django?

Tags: python, django, django-generic-views

I want to display objects based on the datetime information they have. My model looks like this:

**models.py**

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Registration(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    reg_id = models.IntegerField()
    reg_date = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True)
    reg_type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.CharField(max_length-200)
```

**urls.py**

```
from app.models import Registration
from dajngo.views.generic.date_based import archive_day

queryset = registration.objects.all()


urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'ui.views.index'),
    url(r'^registrations/(?P<person_name>)\w+)/(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{2})/(?P<day>\d{2})/$', archive_day, {'year': year, 'month': month, 'day': day, 'queryset': queryset, 'date_field': reg_date})
)

)
```

**My Intent:**

I want to display all the registrations in a person's name, in a particular day. Yes, one person can have more than one registration.

**I know I am wrong:**

I read the docs, but it isn't much handy for a newbie like me. And while I figured out that their are these required parameters and some optional which need to be sent as a `key: value` pair. But what I don't seem to understand is that how can I `reference` the `year`, `month`, `day`, `reg_time` into the `key: value` pair of the dictionary. I mean to say, that obviously it wont recognize what `year` is right? So from where can I get the reference? Do I sound confused? I really am. Some help in clearing it will be much appreciated.

**Update:**

There's one thing I realize. The `date` is really going to be wrapped inside the `request`. Because the user is going to request that `URL` right? So probably I need to extract the values of `year` `month` and `day` from the request body.So how can this be done?

Comment: add  auto_now_add=True to your DateTimeField then for filtering see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12176585/handling-dates-over-request-get

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends, if it's CBV then:

```
self.kwargs['year']
```

if it's the view function then:

```
def my_view(request, year, month, day):
    ...
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/http/urls/#notes-on-capturing-text-in-urls