# Converting date and time to iso format in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I output an ISO-8601 formatted string in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573521/how-do-i-output-an-iso-8601-formatted-string-in-javascript)

I am trying to convert a date and time input to an ISO format but I am getting .toISOString is undefined?  I have to be missing something silly.

```
var startDate = "10/11/2012";
var startTime = "12:12:00";

var fullDate = startDate + " " + startTime;
var fullDateReal = new Date(fullDate);

var iso = fullDateReal.toISOString();
```

Why would .toISOString() show as undefined?

I need to end up with the ISO format ("2012-10-11T12:12") timezone is optional.

**Update**
It looks like this problem is because IE8 does not support this.  So how could I go about converting my inputs to the format listed?

Comment: Works for me http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/SNBdP/

Comment: What browser are you looking at this in?

Comment: It works for me in jsfiddle too.  But debugging in VS2010 through IE 8 it doesn't.

Comment: IE8 doesn't fully support ECMAScript 5, @Adam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some browsers don't support ECMAScript 5 (which is required for toISOString).

http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/

Comment: I saw this after my comment above.  That makes sense as to why it's not working.  So then how would be a good way to convert to the format I need?

Comment: See this other SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573521/how-do-i-output-an-iso-8601-formatted-string-in-javascript

Comment: Cool this answered the main question of why it was not working and posed the correct alternative. Thanks.