# How Do I Convert a Unix Timestamp to ISO 8601 in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have a timestamp like this `1331209044000` and I want to convert it to an ISO 8601 timestamp. How can I convert it using JavaScript?

I use the jQuery "timeago" plugin - http://timeago.yarp.com/

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601 for more information about the standard. I'm afraid you simply have to build a string based on the `Date` components.

Comment: This looks promising:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573521/how-do-i-output-an-iso-8601-formatted-string-in-javascript

Answer (score 127, accepted):

Assuming your timestamp is in milliseconds (or you can convert to milliseconds easily) then you can use the [`Date` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) and the [`date.toISOString()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString).

```javascript
var s = new Date(1331209044000).toISOString();
s; // => "2012-03-08T12:17:24.000Z"
```

If you target older browsers which do not support EMCAScript 5th Edition then you can use the strategies listed in this question: [How do I output an ISO 8601 formatted string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573521/how-do-i-output-an-iso-8601-formatted-string-in-javascript)

Comment: This is ECMAScript 5 - See here for compatibility and fallback code:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString

Comment: Do not forget, that unix timestamp is in seconds, but Javascript counts in miliseconds. So it is actually `new Date(timestamp * 1000).toISOString();`.

Comment: This comment is for future me: IT HAS TO BE IN MILISECONDS !

Answer (score 1):

The solution i used, thanks to the links provided

```
// convert to ISO 8601 timestamp
function ISODateString(d){
    function pad(n){return n<10 ? '0'+n : n}
    return d.getUTCFullYear()+'-'
        + pad(d.getUTCMonth()+1)+'-'
        + pad(d.getUTCDate())+'T'
        + pad(d.getUTCHours())+':'
        + pad(d.getUTCMinutes())+':'
        + pad(d.getUTCSeconds())+'Z'
}

var d = new Date(parseInt(date));
console.log(ISODateString(d));
```

Comment: Of course, this function assumes that the date is actually in the Zulu (GMT+0) timezone.