# Convert JS date to a specific format from unix timestamp

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have a unix timestamp and I want to convert it to a format like this `2018-09-01T12:06:54+0000`

The closest I found is this way `new Date(unix_timestamp).toISOString()`

But, this prints it in the following manner `1970-01-18T04:14:15.076Z`

How can I print it in the format mentioned above?

Comment: It's pretty strange, I done [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12868176/convert-unix-timestamp-to-iso-8601) and it worked (read the first answer), may we see your unix_timestamp?

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question. Can I have the `+0000` instead of `Z`?

Comment: provide an example value for `unix_timestamp`, if it is in seconds, you need to multiply by 1000 because the Date contrusctor takes milliseconds as parameter:
ex: `new Date(unix_timestamp_in_sec * 1000).`