# How to convert date in milliseconds to iso format javascript?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I output an ISO-8601 formatted string in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573521/how-do-i-output-an-iso-8601-formatted-string-in-javascript)

If I have an integer that represents a date in milliseconds, what is the syntax to convert this to an iso format?

Comment: In milliseconds from what?

Comment: @Xander - Could be Unix epoch, but who knows? Perhaps some other epoch?

Comment: @Asad - Chances are [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

Comment: what have you tried? `Date` sounds like a good place to start, as does MDN IMHO

Comment: @LastCoder That is the reverse of what the OP is asking for.

Comment: @Asad - the answers in the linked question show the "new Date(ms).toISOString()" as well as an implementation for toISOString if it's not available. I think this is a case of the symmetric property of Q&A :)

Comment: @LastCoder I can't seem to find `toISOString` on that page at all.

Comment: @Asad - Indeed! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573521/how-do-i-output-an-iso-8601-formatted-string-in-javascript is the one I intended to select for the duplicate, something must of went awry (clearly PEBKAC because the question titles were so similar).

Comment: @LastCoder That one is perfect. I'll try to get the question reopened and closed as a duplicate of that one.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Check out the [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object:

```
new Date(ms).toISOString()
```

Notice that this method might not be available in older browsers, but you can [shim it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString#Compatibility) for them.

Answer (score 0):

```
new Date(value);
```

[from here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), where value represent the milliseconds since 1970. And you could then call
[toISOString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) on yr date object.