# aspmvc post datetime with json error

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

When i post a DateTime with Json i have the following error:
Error 500 Can't cast object of type "System.DateTime" to type "System.Array".

I don't understant why !
Can you help me please ?

**the header send look like this :**

```
{"MyDate":"2012-12-31T23:00:00.000Z","Param1":"aaaa","IdItem":123}
```

**My viewModel :**

```
 public class MyViewModel
 {
public DateTime MyDate { get; set; }
public string Param1 {get;set;}
public Int32? IdItem { get; set; }
 }
```

**My controller :**

```
[HttpPost]
    public void Saisie(MyViewModel model)
    { ... }
```

**My Javascript code :**

```
$.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data : JSON.stringify(model),
        contentType: 'application/json',
success : function() {...}
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found my problem, in the view model i have :

```
public class MyViewModel
{
[MaxLength(10)]
public DateTime MyDate { get; set; }
}
```

the MaxLength attribut cause the error

Comment: I just had this problem today, I'd commented a property out, but not the DataAnnotations above it...and there was a DateTime below...drove me crazy for a couple of hours.  Thanks for posting your own solution for the greater good.

Answer (score 2):

Use  **data: $(form).serialize()** instead of  **data : JSON.stringify(model)**

Comment: i can't use $(form), i need to post a js variable.

Comment: Try changing the date format before the ajax post. The following link could be helpful.[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573521/how-do-i-output-an-iso-8601-formatted-string-in-javascript