# Date format not maintained in jquery post

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

In my MVC 4 project developed in VS2010, I have a screen that has a dropdown that shows date as dd-MMM-yyyy for the display text, with the underlying value as dd-mm-yyyy.

In the function that posts the data, I can see that the selected value is in dd-mm-yyy when I alert it out.

```
  alert($("#dropdwn_BirthDateVal").val());
```

This line above shows my date as desired in dd-mm-yyyy format.

However in the same method when I try to post that value to my controller

```
  $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:"@Url.Content("~/Home/GetUserDetails")",
            async:false,
            dataType: "JSON",
            data: {
                 //.....other string and integer values
                 //.....that go thru properly
                "myDto.DOB":  $("#dropdwn_BirthDateVal").val()
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert(error);

           },

           ..... remaining code here
```

...the date comes in as `1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM`

The controller action I am posting to, 'GetUserDetails' has a ViewModel class called UserVM as its paramter. UserVM has a dto class called MyDto. Within MyDto is a Date property called DOB of type DateTime. MyDto has other properties as well. The string and integer values go thru properly.

What am I missing?

Comment: Probably your server-side marshaller doesn't recognize or isn't expecting "dd-mm-yyyy" as a valid date pattern. I haven't worked in .net, is there someway to specify in your DTO the date pattern to use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to format the date as ISO-8601 when sending it to the server, e.g. `2011-12-19T15:28:46.493Z`

This answer to [this similiar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573521/how-do-i-output-an-iso-8601-formatted-string-in-javascript) shows a number of way to accomplish this, my favorite is `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(new Date()))` but that won't support IE7.

Comment: if you convert it to string and send it to the controller, the parameter where it is being assigned is of type DateTime. Wont there be a problem? I am not at my development box now to try it out.

Comment: No, the .net serializer will know how to handle oy based on the type being assigned to and the format oh the input string

Answer (score 1):

The `DateTime` received turns into `1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM` because the date format (dd-mm-yyyy) could not be parsed properly. When the framework cannot parse your date/time string the result is what you have above.

The result depends on the localization of your machine. For example, under `en-US` localization, the .NET framework expects the date format to be in `MM/dd/yyyy` by default. But you can explicitly specify the format of the date as follows.

```
using System.Globalization;

// dateString is the string in your dd-MM-yyyy format
public void GetValidDate(string dateString) 
{
    DateTime parsedDateTime;
    DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, "dd-MM-yyyy", null, 
                               DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedDateTime)
}
```

Look at the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Actually, I know its not getting parsed. Why is it not getting parsed and how to fix it was what I was looking for. I changed the location settings to US, UK, FR on the development pc and it all had the same effect. The date still came in as 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM