# what's this date format ? 2006-09-01T07:00:00.000+0000 ? is it ISO_8601 ?

Tags: date-format, momentjs, iso8601

I am working on REST calls where I need to send date in "2006-09-01T07:00:00.000+0000" format.

User enters date in "YYYY/MM/DD" format and I am using "moment.js" to format the date in ISO 8601 using this format "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.MMMZ" . But it gives me this output "1969-06-20T00:06:00.Jun-07:00".

So, how do I get date in this format "2006-09-01T07:00:00.000+0000" using moment.js OR Javascript ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I output an ISO-8601 formatted string in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573521/how-do-i-output-an-iso-8601-formatted-string-in-javascript)

Comment: Uppercase `M` is for months and lowercase `m` is for minutes. You should check the required case for other parts of it too.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Yes, it is ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Times).  `2006-09-01T07:00:00.000+0000` is the first day of the ninth month of the year 2006, 7 hours, 0 minutes, 0.000 seconds offset 0 hours from UTC.  Whether or not decimals are allowed is up to the parties exchanging dates (which is a fancy way of ISO saying "it's optional").

> **4.2.2.4 Representations with decimal fraction**
>
> If necessary for a particular application a decimal fraction of hour, minute or second may be included. If a decimal fraction is included, lower order time elements (if any) shall be omitted and the decimal fraction shall be divided from the integer part by the decimal sign specified in ISO 31-0, i.e. the comma [,] or full stop [.]. Of these, the comma is the preferred sign. If the magnitude of the number is less than unity, the decimal sign shall be preceded by two zeros in accordance with 3.6.
>
> The interchange parties, dependent upon the application, shall agree the number of digits in the decimal fraction. The format shall be [hhmmss,ss], [hhmm,mm] or [hh,hh] as appropriate (hour minute second, hour minute, and hour, respectively), with as many digits as necessary following the decimal sign. A decimal fraction shall have at least one digit. In the examples below it has been agreed to give the smallest time element a decimal fraction with one digit.

(As pointed out by @chansen, *technically* it should be `2006-09-01T07:00:00.000+00:00` with a separator on the time zone because according to 4.3.3(d) every part must use either the basic format (no separators) or the extended format (with separators), but nobody bothers with that, strptime can't produce that format, and you'll probably *break* some ISO 8601 parsers).

Outputting this is covered in other answers for both [Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8563517/14660) and [moment.js](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15302113/14660).

Javascript has [Date.toISOString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) for output. [Date.new](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) will also accept an ISO 8601 string. Every recent browser should support it, though Internet Explorer only added it in version 9 ([IE 8 still represents 5% of desktop users](http://gs.statcounter.com/#desktop-browser_version_partially_combined-ww-monthly-201410-201412-bar)).

Here's the [moment.js docs on String formatting](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/).  `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.MMMZ` is incorrect because you're using `M` to mean three different things.  What you want is `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSZZ`.

- YYYY - year
- MM - month number (2 digit)
- DD - day of month (2 digit)
- HH - hours (2 digit, 24 hour format)
- mm - minutes (2 digit)
- ss - seconds (2 digit)
- SSS - thousands of seconds
- ZZ - UTC offset

Comment: Actually, it's an invalid ISO 8601 representation. The zone designator can't be in basic format when the date and time is in extended format.

Comment: @chansen 4.3.3(d), there it is. You are technically correct (the best kind of correct)! I don't think it matters in practice, everyone screws that one up. I don't think you can even get strptime to output the time zone with a separator.

Answer (score 0):

The format that worked for me for 2006-09-01T07:00:00.000+0000

was: yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.sssZ