# Convert date into different formats in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I convert a date in this format 'Sat Feb 14 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (ora solare Europa occidentale)' into a date in this format '2015-02-05T10:17:13' using javascript?

Comment: Using plain `JavaScript` it wouldn't be so easy. I would suggest you use a library, like `moment.js` and this would be two lines of code. http://momentjs.com/

Comment: 'Sat Feb 14 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (ora solare Europa occidentale)'  is a string, isn't it?

Comment: Have you forgotten comma? Sat, Feb 14 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a library, called [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/). With it, you can parse datetime-strings in many representational formats, and convert them back, in whatever datetime format you like.

Answer (score 1):

The date you want to get to is basically the ISO-8601 standard.

```
var date = new Date('Sat Feb 14 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0100');
var iso8601 = date.toISOString();
console.log(iso8601); // 2015-02-13T23:00:00.000Z
```

This conversion is based on ECMAScript 5 (ECMA-262 5th edition) so won't be available in older versions of JS. Other answers are correct moment js will significantly improve your date conversions.

Courtesy of this [MDN Page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) and [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8563517/2202642). If you expect to be supporting pre EC5 you can use the polyfill:

```
if ( !Date.prototype.toISOString ) {
( function() {

  function pad(number) {
    var r = String(number);
    if ( r.length === 1 ) {
      r = '0' + r;
    }
    return r;
  }

  Date.prototype.toISOString = function() {
    return this.getUTCFullYear()
      + '-' + pad( this.getUTCMonth() + 1 )
      + '-' + pad( this.getUTCDate() )
      + 'T' + pad( this.getUTCHours() )
      + ':' + pad( this.getUTCMinutes() )
      + ':' + pad( this.getUTCSeconds() )
      + '.' + String( (this.getUTCMilliseconds()/1000).toFixed(3) ).slice( 2, 5 )
      + 'Z';
  };

}() );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look:

[All you will need about date in JS](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp)

Answer (score 0):

#### Using `Date.parse()` and `Date.toISOString()`

```
var input = "Sat, Feb 14 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0100"
input = Date.parse(input);
input = new Date(input);
input = input.toISOString(); // "2015-02-13T23:00:00.000Z"
```