# JavaScript Date.prototype.toISOString() loses offset

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, timezone

Why does this method use UTC timezone (`Z`) and not include the local time offset (`+/-HH:SS`) instead? The "ISO" in the method name [refers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) to ISO 8601—which allows for ["time zone designations"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators) to be expressed as part of its format.

In other words, `new Date()` tells me both the date and time, and the timezone offset (via `getTimezoneOffset()`). But `toISOString()` only tells me the date and time in *one* timezone—it discards the information of what time it was in the locale that the `new Date()` originated.

Wouldn't it make sense for `toISOString()` to also include the originating timezone's offset from UTC? `toISOString()`'s omission of +/-HH:SS loses information about the *originating* `Date` if it's used for serializing.

All my AJAX calls (Angular, jQuery) serialize via `toISOString()`, thus losing the local time of the serialized date when it's communicated to the server. Any way to get a JavaScript `Date` to output an ISO-formatted string *that also includes* offset (besides using a library like Moment.js), or do I need to write my own method?

Comment: not sure what the problem is... it will always convert back to the same exact time in your timezone using `Date` object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one of those "because that's what the language specification says" answers (see [*ECMA-262 §20.3.4.36*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-date.prototype.toisostring)). ISO 8601 is a format, and while it allows the use of timezone data, ECMAScript only uses UTC. You can extend *Date.prototype* with your own *toLocalISOString* method if you wish. BTW, writing such a method is not difficult.

```js
// Format date as ISO 8601 long format with local timezone offset
if (!Date.prototype.toLocalISOString) {
  Date.prototype.toLocalISOString = function() {
  
  // Helper for padding
  function pad(n, len) {
    return ('000' + n).slice(-len);
  }

  // If not called on a Date instance, or timevalue is NaN, return undefined
  if (isNaN(this) || Object.prototype.toString.call(this) != '[object Date]') return;

  // Otherwise, return an ISO format string with the current system timezone offset
  var d = this;
  var os = d.getTimezoneOffset();
  var sign = (os > 0? '-' : '+');
  os = Math.abs(os);

  return pad(d.getFullYear(), 4) + '-' +
         pad(d.getMonth() + 1, 2) + '-' +
         pad(d.getDate(), 2) +
         'T' + 
         pad(d.getHours(), 2) + ':' +
         pad(d.getMinutes(), 2) + ':' +
         pad(d.getSeconds(), 2) + '.' +
         pad(d.getMilliseconds(), 3) + 
       
         // Note sign of ECMASCript offsets are opposite to ISO 8601
         sign +
         pad(os/60 | 0, 2) + ':' +
         pad(os%60, 2);
  }
}
document.write(new Date().toLocalISOString())
```

#### Edit

Based on a [post by DanDascalescu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573521/how-do-i-output-an-iso-8601-formatted-string-in-javascript/39477406#39477406), here's an alternative that might be more efficient as it has fewer function calls, but it creates two additional Date objects:

```js
// Return a string in ISO 8601 extended format with the host timezone offset
Date.prototype.toLocalISOString = function() {

    // If not called on a Date instance, or timevalue is NaN, return undefined
    if (isNaN(this) || Object.prototype.toString.call(this) != '[object Date]') return;

    // Copy date so don't modify original
    var d = new Date(+this);
    var offset = d.getTimezoneOffset();
    var offSign = offset > 0? '-' : '+';
    offset = Math.abs(offset);
    var tz = offSign + ('0' + (offset/60|0)).slice(-2) + ':' + ('0' + offset%60).slice(-2)
    return new Date(d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() - d.getTimezoneOffset())).toISOString().slice(0,-1) + tz; 
}

console.log(new Date().toLocalISOString())
```

Comment: @JuanMendes—this doesn't break any existing behaviour, it adds a new method. Admittedly there's the possibility of a name clash with some future version of ECMAScript, but since most of the date formatting has been handed to [*ECMA-402*](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-402.htm), hopefully similar functionality wont be added to *Date.prototype*.

Comment: @DanDascalescu—that is **not** the same thing. All the "simpler way" does is trim the time zone from a UTC date and time so that it also loses its absolute reference. It becomes a different moment in time zones with different offsets. This answer includes the host time zone offset, so it keeps it's absolute reference.