# Create JavaScript Date object from date string + time string + timezone offset string

Tags: javascript, datetime, timestamp, momentjs

I have total 4 different input i.e.:

1. Date string (2020-05-05)
2. Time string (15:30)
3. Timezone offset (-09:00)

I want to combine these strings into one datetime object like (2020-05-05T15:30:00-09:00) no-matter what my local browser timezone is. The issue is when I combine these strings and I try to make date object using new Date() function, my datetime gets converted into UTC timestamp.

I tried this:

```
const date =
  moment(this.actualDateOfSurgeryDate).format(YYYYMMDD) +
  'T' +
  moment(this.actualDateOfSurgeryTimeDropDown + ' ' + this.actualDateOfSurgeryTimeAM_PMDropDown, ['h:mm A']).format('HH:mm:ss') +
  offsetTime;

this.caseDetail.actualDateOfSurgery = new Date(date);
```

This gives me output something like: 2020-05-05T04:30:00.000Z

How can I get my desired output: 2020-05-05T15:30:00-09:00 ??
I have moment js available in my project

Comment: Do you want to ignore the timezone entirely?

Comment: Actually I have dedicated timezone selection as dropdown listing all timezones and I get selected timezone offset as '-09:00' which I want to append as it is in my timestamp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to combine these strings into one datetime object like (2020-05-05T15:30:00-09:00)

Date objects are extremely simple, they're just a time value that is an offset in milliseconds since 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z, so are inherently UTC. The built–in parser is unreliable and lacks any functionality such as format tokens.

So if you have separate values like:

> - Date string (2020-05-05)
> - Time string (15:30)
> - Timezone offset (-09:00)

then you can create a string that is compliant with the format [defined in ECMA-262](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-date-time-string-format) and that *should* be parsed correctly by the built–in parser, e.g.

```
new Date('2020-05-05T15:30:00.000-09:00')
```

However, general advice is to avoid the built–in parser due to differences in implementations. Also, the format must be exact (e.g. including seconds and milliseconds in the timestamp, colon (:) in the offset) or some implementations will reject it as malformed and return an invalid date.

Once you have a Date object, getting a "local" timestamp with offset is an issue of formatting, which has been answered many times before (e.g. [*How to format a JavaScript date*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date?r=SearchResults&s=1|1450.4192)). There aren't any decent built–in formatting functions ([toLocaleString with options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) is OK for some purposes but generally lacking in functionality), so you'll have to either [write your own function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33027329/257182), or use a library.

The following examples use [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/index.html), which is suggested as the upgrade path from moment.js.

With Luxon, if you specify a representative location, you'll get the offset for that location at the date's date and time. Alternatively, you can fix the offset to a set value, essentially setting it for a timezone without a representative location, so it doesn't have any reference to daylight saving or historic offset changes:

```js
let DateTime = luxon.DateTime;

// Offset per the specified location
let d0 = DateTime.fromISO('2020-01-01', {zone: 'America/Yakutat'});
let d1 = DateTime.fromISO('2020-06-30', {zone: 'America/Yakutat'});
console.log(d0.toString());
console.log(d1.toString());

// Fixed offset per the supplied string
let d2 = DateTime.fromISO('2020-05-05T15:30:00.000-09:00', { setZone: true});
let d3 = DateTime.fromISO('2020-01-01T15:30:00.000-09:00', { setZone: true});
console.log(d2.toString());
console.log(d3.toString());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/luxon@1.24.1/build/global/luxon.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I get 16:30 due to DST

A date before March or after October will give 15:30

```js
let dateString = "2020-05-05"+"T"+"15:30"+":00"+"-09:00"
console.log(dateString)
const date = new Date(dateString)
console.log(date)
const Anchorage = date.toLocaleString('en-US', {timeZone: 'America/Anchorage', hour12: false})
console.log(Anchorage)

let options = {}
options.timeZone = 'America/Anchorage';
options.timeZoneName = 'short';
console.log(date.toLocaleDateString('en-US'), date.toLocaleTimeString('en-US', options));
```

Comment: This does work but I don't have timezone area name. I just have offset like '-09:00'

Comment: So make a lookup table from Wikipedia and mdn. That’s how found anchorage