# How to add timestamp in a date in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have one date "2017-11-30 07:15:45.3520000", I want to convert this date to "2017-11-30T07:15:45.352Z". How to convert to this format in javascript.

Comment: If you do not know yet what we expect of you before asking here, please go read [ask]. This shows no research effort at all.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/ Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573521/how-do-i-output-an-iso-8601-formatted-string-in-javascript, probably several others.

Comment: Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var n = new Date("2017-11-30 07:15:45.3520000Z").toISOString();
    console.log(n);
```

add one "Z" to your time string. Eg: "2017-11-30 07:15:45.3520000Z"

Comment: Doesn't adding the z make it the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `toISOString` method like this:

```js
var date = new Date("2017-11-30 07:15:45.3520000");
console.log(date.toISOString());
```

Comment: I have tried above code. But I'm getting "2017-11-30T01:45:45.352Z" this time. But I need "2017-11-30T07:15:45.352Z" time.