# needs understanding of this format of date and time

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I just came across this format of start and end in the codebase which is probably the starting and ending date and time.However, I could not figure out this.
I know how to generate date and time in javascript but I need to generate it in this format to be able to fetch data from API.
Here is the format.

```
 start : '2018-06-20T11:44:21.938Z',
 end : '2018-07-20T11:44:21.938Z',
```

At the same time, I would like to know how to get date and time with exact this format?

Answer (score 1):

```
let date = new Date( Date.parse('2018-06-20T11:44:21.938Z'));
```

To retrieve date & time separately.

```
date.toLocaleDateString();
date.toLocaleTimeString()'
```

To convert any date object to your desired format (ISO Dates):

```
var date = new Date();
date.toISOString();
```

Comment: Can you tell me how to generate date exact this way?Y es, your answer helped to understand.

Answer (score 1):

```
var date = new Date(Date.parse('2018-06-20T11:44:21.938Z'));
```

It's ISO 8601 format.
Check this:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Answer (score 1):

It is [ISO format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) of the date. You can use [`toISOString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) method to achieve it:

```js
// current date
var date = new Date();
console.log(date);
console.log(date.toISOString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `toISOString()` in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toisostring)

```
var event = new Date('05 October 2011 14:48 UTC');
console.log(event.toString());
// expected output: Wed Oct 05 2011 16:48:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)
// (note: your timezone may vary)

console.log(event.toISOString());
// expected output: 2011-10-05T14:48:00.000Z
```

Answer (score 0):

That is the ISO date format.

similar to this:

[How do I output an ISO 8601 formatted string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573521/how-do-i-output-an-iso-8601-formatted-string-in-javascript)

Here is code to produce it.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.toISOString();
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">convert to ISO date format</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is an ISO date. Check this link for some info:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_formats.asp

```
var istDate = new Date(); // will return: Wed Sep 05 2018 17:50:39 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
var isoDate = istDate.toISOString(); // will return in ISO format i.e. "2018-09-05T12:20:39.732Z"
var dateString = istDate.toDateString(); // will return in format: "Wed Sep 05 2018"
```

Browser console will provide suggestions for various methods of Date Object for extracting day, month, year, etc from the `new Date()`