# Using JSONata in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, datetime, jsonata

I am a JavaScript student and came across JSONata recently.

I am creating an application where our backend requires us to send the date time field in following format: `"2019-04-25T11:36:30.254Z"`

I see that we can get this using JSONata by using $now() function.

I am not sure how we can use JSONata with JavaScript. Or is there a way to get date time in above format using JavaScript?

I tried below till now but not successful:

```
    var jsonata = require("jsonata");
    var date_now = jsonata("$now");
    console.log(date_now)
```

I also tried simple javascript date time objects but that does not give me the required format.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I output an ISO 8601 formatted string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573521/how-do-i-output-an-iso-8601-formatted-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

To invoke JSONata, you need to do the following...

```
var jsonata = require("jsonata");
var date_now = jsonata("$now()").evaluate();
console.log(date_now)
```

However, if you only need it to format the date to ISO8601, then using JSONata is probably a bit overkill.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the native JavaScript method [Date.toISOString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) like in the following example:

```js
let d = new Date()
console.log(d.toISOString())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use .toJSON

```js
var jsonDate = (new Date()).toJSON();
console.log(jsonDate);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toJSON