# How can I convert this date to a string whilst maintaining format?

Tags: javascript, date

In short this function returns a time which is then used to query a JSON file, it seems for the query to work my date needs to be in string format, It will not work if I pass the result of `recent_time()` into the query.

```
function recent_time(process) {
    date_array = []

    for (var object in process) {
        var processtime = new Date(process[object]);
        date_array.push(processtime)
    }

    max_date = new Date(Math.max.apply(null, date_array));
    return max_date
}
```

Currently the value returned is in the format `2019-05-22T11:01:18.000Z` I need it to read as this (for my json query purpose):

`"2019-05-22T11:01:18.000Z"` - note it is in string format

I have tried `return max_date.toString()` However this returns the format

`Wed May 22 2019 11:01:18 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)`

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Use `max_date.toISOString()`

Comment: Did you try consulting the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Conversion_getter) to see if a suitable function existed (or whether you could create such a format from the functions available)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I output an ISO 8601 formatted string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573521/how-do-i-output-an-iso-8601-formatted-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for the `.toISOString()` method.