# how to Convert Date into ISO Date Format in javascript

Tags: javascript, momentjs

i have a date like this which i should convert them into ISO format

`const date = 05/23/2022;`

i need like this

2022-05-23T00:00:00Z

Comment: [toISOString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I output an ISO 8601 formatted string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573521/how-do-i-output-an-iso-8601-formatted-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`String.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to get the day, month and year for the Date in question.

We can then pass to the [`Date.UTC()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC) function and then the [`Date()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date) constructor. (Note: We pass *monthIndex* to the Date constructor, that's why we subtract 1 from the month )

To display as an ISO string, we can then use [`Date.toISOString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)

```js
const [month, day, year] = '05/23/2022'.split('/');
const date = new Date(Date.UTC(year, month - 1, day));
const result = date.toISOString();
console.log('Date (ISO):', result);
```

We can also do this easily with a Date / Time library such as [`luxon`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/?id=luxon).

We'd use the [`DateTime.fromFormat()`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimefromformat) function to parse the input string, setting the timezone to 'UTC'.

To output the ISO date, we can use the [`DateTime.toISO()`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimetoiso) function:

```js
const { DateTime } = luxon;
const date = DateTime.fromFormat('05/23/2022', 'MM/dd/yyyy', { zone: 'UTC'});
console.log('Date (ISO):', date.toISO())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/luxon/2.3.1/luxon.min.js" integrity="sha512-Nw0Abk+Ywwk5FzYTxtB70/xJRiCI0S2ORbXI3VBlFpKJ44LM6cW2WxIIolyKEOxOuMI90GIfXdlZRJepu7cczA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

We can also do this in moment.js, using [`moment.utc()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/), then [`.toISOString()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-iso-string/):

```js
const date = moment.utc('05/23/2022', 'MM/DD/YYYY');
console.log('Date (ISO):', date.toISOString())
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: He might be using `moment.js` since he tags the question with `moment`

Answer (score 3):

Note that `.toISOString()` always returns a timestamp in **UTC**, even if the moment in question is in local mode. This is done to provide consistency with the specification for native JavaScript Date `.toISOString()`, as outlined in the `ES2015` specification.

```js
let date = '24.05.2022 0:00:00';
let parsedDate = moment(date, 'DD.MM.YYYY H:mm:ss')
console.log(parsedDate.toISOString());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```